# Version update issue after registration of new version of App Store

Tags: android, app-update

Version update issue after registration of new version of App Store.

Most users successfully updated their version through the App Store.
1.0.0 -> 1.1.0

However, some users have succeeded in the update and the function was added, but the version remained the same.
1.0.0 -> 1.0.0

The problem is that when you run the app, you are asked to update it, and the app store says there is nothing to update.

I do not know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
String current_app_version = getCurrentVersionInfo();
                            System.out.println("current_app_version : " + current_app_version);
                            System.out.println("version_from_server : " + version);
                            if (!current_app_version.contentEquals(version)) {

                                displayPopup();
                            }



    private String getCurrentVersionInfo() {
    String strVersion = "";

    PackageInfo packageInfo;
    try {
        packageInfo = Home.this
                .getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(
                        Home.this.getPackageName(),
                        0
                );
        strVersion = packageInfo.versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    }
    System.out.println("strVersion : " + strVersion);
    return strVersion;
}
```